# Nhibernate Rollback and Check success of Transaction with Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, stored-procedures

I have a scenario where I have a stored procedure that needs to run. This proc is an advanced delete touching somewhere around 13 interrelated tables. However, I also need to clear out some XML, but only if the proc is successful. That is my first question: *How do I determine if the proc is successful for CreateSQLQuery?* Once that is determined, I'm passing the XML delete in as a func. If that fails, then I want to roll the whole thing back.There is my second question: *How do I do a rollback on a stored procedure?* If I simply call the rollback it would appear that the data still deletes.

```
public void DeleteWithCondition(int id, func<bool> condition)
    {

        using (var session = _factory.OpenSession())
        using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {

            session.CreateSQLQuery(string.Format("EXEC DeleteItem '{0}'", id));

            //Logic to check success of stored proc

            if (!condition())
                transaction.Rollback(); //If logic fails, then roll back transaction

        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to ensure that the stored procedure doesn't create its own transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`session.CreateSQLQuery(...).ExecuteUpdate();` will execute it and fail with an exception if the database says so.